# Req.body Destructuring problem in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-development-server

I am trying to get title, description and tag for updating them in my note app but on de structuring them title is undefined is showing please resolve this error

Trying to resolve the error:

```js
Router.put('/updateNote/:id', fetchuser, async (res, req) => {

    //create a new note object
    const {title, description,tag}=req.body;
    try {
        // Create a newNote object
        const newNote = {};
        if (title) { newNote.title = title };
        if (description) { newNote.description = description };
        if (tag) { newNote.tag = tag };


        //find the noteto be updated update it
        let note = await Notes.findById(req.params.id); //above id which you want to update /updatenote/:id
        // Now we have the note which you want to update 
        //?case 1 ===> note is not present

        if (!note) { return res.status(404).send("Not Found") }

        if (note.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
            return res.status(401).send("Not Allowed");
        }
        note = await Notes.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: newNote }, { new: true })
        res.json({ note });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
})
```

```bash
D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\routes\notes.js:48
    const {title, description,tag}=req.body;
           ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.        
    at D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\routes\notes.js:48:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
    at next (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at fetchuser (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\Middleware\Fetchuser.js:14:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
    at next (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
    at D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at param (D:\Web development\React.js\inotes\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: According to the API reference, the first param always contain request req, then response res.

So change first param res to req:
'
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Rendering file")
}
'
It should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```js
Router.put('/updateNote/:id', fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
  // ... the rest of the code
}
```